# Swift SpriteKit: "MCTFruit does not have a member named append?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, append

I have code typed out for an obstacle, and with the line   fruits.append(fruits) I get the (see above) error, but with the line directly below it, fruitTracker.append(fruits), everything works perfectly. 
Help? Thanks in advance(:

Here is my code for the class:

```
class MCTFruitGen: SKSpriteNode {
var generationTimer: NSTimer!

var fruits = [MCTFruit]()
var fruitTracker = [MCTFruit]()

func startGeneratingFruitEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {


    generationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "generateFruit", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func stopGenerating() {
    generationTimer?.invalidate()
}
func generateFruit() {

    var scale: CGFloat
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(2)
    if rand == 0 {
        scale = -1.0
    } else {
        scale = 1.0
    }

    let fruits = MCTFruit()


    fruits.position.x = size.width/2 + fruits.size.width/2

    fruits.position.y = scale * (NMCGroundHeight/160 + fruits.size.height)

    fruits.append(fruits)

    fruitTracker.append(fruits)
    addChild(fruits)
}

func stopFruit() {
    stopGenerating()
    for fruit in fruits {
        fruit.stopFruitMoving()


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `generateFruit` you have created a local variable called `fruits` which is hiding your class property `fruits`:

```
let fruits = MCTFruit()
```

Then in this line, you are referring to `fruits`, wanting one to be the local variable and one to be the class property:

```
fruits.append(fruits)
```

The compiler will use the local variable, which is why you're getting the error because `fruits` (an instance of `MCTFruit`) doesn't have an append method.

You could fix this by saying:

```
self.fruits.append(fruits)
```

but I would recommend you chose another name for your local variable:

```
let fruit = MCTFruit()
fruits.append(fruit)
```